# Can I use fully qualified object names in sqlcmd variables applied in a Visual Studio Database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sqlcmd

We have a Database project that has a join on a table on another database. Since the other database name may change, the reference to the other database is referenced with a sqlcmd variable, i.e. `inner join [$(otherdb)].Table1 ...` for which we have deployment parameters set up.

Now I am trying to make this project deployable to a local instance of SQL Server for us as developers, and I would like to *not* have to deploy also the referenced database on the same machine. So, I am conditionally ($(IsLocal)='true') setting up a linked server to point to our dev SQL DB server and for local deployments only I am trying to set up the $(otherdb) variable to have a value of: `linkedserver.otherdb` rather than just `otherdb`.

This works in SQL with the linked server and manually executing the actual queries but does not seem to work for the sqlcmd-mode based deployments. It turns out the square brackets make the output along the lines of `[linkedserver.otherdb].Table1` (rather than `[linkedserver].[otherdb].Table1`) and if I just remove the square brackets (`linkedserver.otherdb.Table1`) I get a build-time error for the Database project saying invalid syntax. So the square brackets have to be there but the fully qualified nested name makes it invalid.

I also tried using the sqlcmd variable value of `linkedserver].[otherdb` to result in the generated query of [ ***linkedserver].[otherdb*** ].[Table1]. This, too, works in SQL when I try sqlcmd execution, but when Visual Studio generates the script it adds an extra `]` resulting in:

```
:setvar otherdb "linkedserver]].[otherdb"
```

If I remove the extra `]` it does work, but there is no way to intervene on this generated output in T-SQL script without a cmd or PowerShell script. (Is there?)

Is there another approach I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue, and no matter how much I thought about it, I was unable to find an elegant solution to the problem. Your options essentially are:

1. Complete your DEV environment by deploying an empty (or almost empty) referenced database to the same server. Everything will work, no code changes are required.
2. Rewrite all your relevant code to use 4-part identifiers for the referenced database. The DEV environment will work fine; the PROD will require a loop-back linked server that points to itself, so that objects in the referenced database can be accessed using 4-part names. This will probably introduce a performance bottleneck, apart from other potential issues.

See for yourself which way is easier or more acceptable.

Comment: Thanks. For now, we are settling on the "linkedserver].[otherdb" variable name approach, and hand editing the generated script to remove the double-bracket. This seems to be the least obtuse approach, and at some point I will create a powershell script to generate the same script without UI (as in, build the database project and package a script targeting the local environment xml), alter the script output to remove the double-bracket, and invoke sqlcmd.exe with the script against localhost, all with one double-click.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hand editing, have you considered creating a predeployment script with a single line of

```
:r $(theconfig)
```

?

And `$(theconfig)` would be a file with a list of `:setvar` commands, e.g.

```
:setvar $(otherdb) "otherserver].[otherdb].[schema"
```

Since the UI isn't injecting the variables, you can provide the values with `]`'s that are not doubled up so that the `[$(somevar)]` format works properly.

Finally, the `$(theconfig)` can be set in the publish profile with multiple configs for multiple environments (each with it's own profile).